# Error when trying to sum an array by block's

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large dataset stored in a numpy array (A) I am trying to sum by block's using:

`B=numpy.add.reduceat(numpy.add.reduceat(A, numpy.arange(0, A.shape[0], n),axis=0), numpy.arange(0, A.shape[1], n), axis=1)`

it work's fine when i try it on a test array but with my data's I get the following message:

`TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'`

Does someone now how to handle this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the `dtype` of `A`?

Comment: Print A.dtype  is >f4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem you're encountering is because your block size, `n`, is a float rather than an integer:

```
>>> A = np.arange(10)

# float block size
>>> np.add.reduceat(A, np.arange(0, A.shape[0], 5.0), axis=0)
# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64')
# according to the rule 'safe'

# integer block size
>>> np.add.reduceat(A, np.arange(0, A.shape[0], 5), axis=0)
# array([10, 35])
```

`numpy.add.reduceat` requires an array of integer indices, but `numpy.arange(0, A.shape[0], 5.0)` returns an array of float64 values.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has a similar problem but the chosen answer doesn't solve it, one possibility could be that in Python3, some index or integer quantity fed into a np function is an expression using '/' for example n/2, which ought to be '//'.